# Horizontal and vertical alignments in a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

Is it possible to align elements horizontal and vertical in a flexbox container?
So you have your html like this:

```
<section class="flex-container">
    <article class="project--vertical project1"></article>
    <article class="project--vertical project2"></article>
    <article class="project--horizontal project3"></article>
    <article class="project--horizontal project4"></article>
    <article class="project--horizontal project5"></article>
</section>
```

An example (that doesn't work yet) can be found at: http://codepen.io/JordyPouw/pen/MYJOde

Answer (score 0):

cross-axis alignment is done with the `align-items` property. `justify-content` is used for aligning along the same axis. It sounds to me like, in your case, you just need to use both of those properties, and set the value to `center`:

```
  .flex-container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work sadly. Tested it on Codepen, but only element with class 'project3' get stacked up next to the first two.

Comment: could you explain how you're intending to align the elements? are they supposed to align top, bottom, left, right?

Comment: The two vertical elements should align next to each other. Next to that the horizontal element should align in a column. Now i did it with creating an element around the vertical projects and an element around the horizontal projects. But i wanna try it without that and use the markup shown above.